# Cannot insert into table in readonly mode

Tags: node.js, clickhouse

I am getting below exception when i am trying to insert records in clickhouse databse:

**Exception:**

```
Code: 164, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot insert into table in readonly mode, e.what() = DB::Exception
```

**Node package:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clickhouse

**Connection code:**

```
const clickhouse = new ClickHouse({
url: 'http://localhost',
port: 8123,
debug: true,
database: 'mydb',
basicAuth: 'default',
username: '',
password: '',
isUseGzip: false,
config: {
    session_timeout                         : 60,
    output_format_json_quote_64bit_integers : 0,
    enable_http_compression                 : 0
},

});
```

**Table schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE logs_1 ( trid UInt64,  date UInt32,  email String) ENGINE = Log;
```

Comment: Your database is in a read-only mode. Why don't you go and read the documentation? Maybe this will help https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/permissions_for_queries/#settings_readonly

Comment: I do not know, how to insert in any other database which currently in read-only mode. It's not possible. Your question is not clear - do you want to ask, how to switch database to normal mode?

Comment: @victor yeah it might be help

Comment: @victor yeah it might help

Comment: So, if problem on backend side, please, make sure you have set up database regarding guidelines (see https://clickhouse.yandex for details) and you're trying to write to non-replicated table, or if so - your Zookeeper is installed correctly. Clickhouse will not allow you to write to replicated table in case when no Zookeeper configured.

Comment: from your question is not clear what query you're trying to execute and is `logs_1` the right table (I see that you're using Log engine, which is not replicated)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- you connect to ClickHouse using user which has readonly flag set in
  user settings / user profile.
- you're trying to insert data using GET
  request instead of POST (probably not your case if you use that
  library)
- you are inserting to replicated tabled and server has no
  connection to zookeeper (not your case as you're inserting to
  non-replicated table with Log engine)

So Please check the setting of default user and profile.  Most probably it contains readonly flag.

Comment: Using GET insted of POST, was my problem exactly. Very helpful answer.